# How do I display an alphabetical list of Webform titles in a block?

Tags: webforms

[new]
**I have a series of Webforms created on my Drupal 8 site. I want to create a view that will list all of them in alphabetical order within a block. How do I create a view that will do this?**
[/new]

[original]
*I want to have a block that displays an alphabetical list of all Webform titles, linked to those forms.

How do I create the view that will do this? I tried displaying anything of Content-type "Webform," but it displays a blank. If I go into Structures->Webforms, it displays all of them with no problem.*
[/original]

Comment: Can't you use Views for that?

Comment: I thought that I could; however, when I do use Views, I'm not getting a list of anything. Webform appears to be a special type - can't access the title of any of them, except by going through admin/structure/webforms

Comment: Webforms are config entities, which Views can't handle out of the box. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/193403/config-entities-and-views-integration

Comment: Thanks for the response. Not the one I was hoping for! I'll go ahead and make a static block with the links instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Config entities and views integration](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/193403/config-entities-and-views-integration)